# Why does margin:0 not work on buttons?

Tags: html, css

I want two buttons to be displayed right next to each other, with no border in between. The buttons are:

```
<button class="tButton">1</button> 
<button class="tButton">2</button>
```

My naive approach for the css is:

```
.tButton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: none;
}
```

But this leaves some space between the buttons ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83a2Lou0/)). In Firefox, the example renders as:

[image: Around 5px between buttons]

This problem goes away when I use `float: left;` on the buttons. But I am trying to understand the following about CSS:

Why is there any margin to begin with, even though I explicitly set `margin: 0;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because by default buttons are inline-block elements, and as any inline/inline-block elements they respect white spaces including new lines.

For this reason putting buttons on the same line gets rid of gaps:

```css
.tButton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="tButton">1</button><button class="tButton">2</button>
```

as well as making them `float: left` since in this case buttons become floated block-level elements.

Comment: other ways to remove the white-space [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 2):

This happens with `inline` and `inline-block` elements. space is added in newline. You should change your markup, from:

```
<button class="tButton">1</button>
<button class="tButton">2</button>
```

To

```
<button class="tButton">1</button><button class="tButton">2</button>
```

single line [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83a2Lou0/7/)

Answer (score 2):

as a variant, you can write:

```
<button class="tButton">1</button
><button class="tButton">2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The body is still a “BIG DIV” which needs to be set with margin zero and give a `display:flex;` so the items on its container will stack one together to the other inline. I checked your code in https://jsfiddle.net/83a2Lou0/ and it needs to be saved first before you see the effect of the changes.

I forked your same code in code pen and there the changes are saved automatically. Just add this to your CSS:

```
body{
margin: 0;
display: flex;
}
.tButton {
/* The same properties and values you have here. */
```

And that‘s it. Check here the same coding:
https://codepen.io/limakid/pen/KKQRdXK